# How do I get Ctrl + Alt + t to launch ther terminal in Linux Mint 13 MATE?

Tags: terminal, gnome, linux-mint, keyboard-shortcuts, mate-desktop

Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>t</kbd> seems to do nothing on my Linux Mint 13 MATE.

How can I set this shortcut to launch a terminal window?

As a detail, it seems the terminal is `mate-terminal` rather than `gnome-terminal`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can just use `Keyboard Shortcuts`, available via Main Menu's *Search* ..

Just `Add` a new item... eg. named `mate-terminal`  ... the command should be  `mate-terminal`

Then click on the new item (which appears at the bottom of the list)..  and type `Control-Alt-t` ...

All done...

If you have `compiz` installed, you can also use its `Commands` options, but the above method should still work.

Comment: This did not work in Debian Jessie.

Comment: @Barracuda it works. I went to Settings -> Keyboard > Shortcuts > Own shortcuts -> Add. Tested on Debian 8.1.0

Answer (score 6):

Go to keyboard shortcut at System Tools -->Preferences-->System Settings-->keyboard-->shortcut
Custom shortcuts

```
add + 
Name: gnome-terminal
Command :gnome-terminal
ctrl+alt+t
```

quickly try that

Comment: This one worked for me. Debian Jessie

Answer (score 0):

Alt-T just try and see. You don't have to add any new shortcut keys